# Background image is not working correctly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-image

I am trying to replicate [this site](https://zoro.to/) which is mostly working fine. But when I try to use `::before` to apply a background image, no matter what I try, it doesn't work as I want.

Here is the code :

```css
/* Section */
section {
    grid-area: section;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

section::before {
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(32, 33, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(32, 33, 37, 0) 64%), url(https://zoro.to/images/zoro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.afterimg {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#search {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#image {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#image img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="afterimg">
        <div id="search">
            search
        </div>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="https://zoro.to/images/zoro.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Which produces [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DevU.png). But I was expecting it to [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DevU.png). I don't understand why the image covers the whole page instead of just the `<section>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to add position: relative to your section selector: `section {position: relative; grid-area: section; border: 2px solid red;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Heghar, please add position: relative; to the section.
In general, section is position-inherit, so you have to add position-relative to the parent which is benchmark of the child, before you add position-absolute to the child. Hope it is helpful to you~.

```css
/* Section */
section {
    grid-area: section;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

section::before {
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(32, 33, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(32, 33, 37, 0) 64%), url(https://zoro.to/images/zoro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.afterimg {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#search {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#image {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#image img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <section>
        <div class="afterimg">
            <div id="search">
                search
            </div>
            <div id="image">
                <img src="https://zoro.to/images/zoro.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```